# Installer for local webapp for stock management using django

Tags: django, web, host

I am looking to build a webapp for stock management, since it does not need to be hosted on the internet( only admin and sellers can access it ), with it's database on the local computer, I need to find a way for making it easier for the sellers to use the webapp without running a server and all that stuff since they are not tech-savvy

Answer (score 0):

A server is not mainly a computer on the internet or cloud. You can use a local computer as a server. [This tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) is a great way to gather all of the Django application's parts into a single docker-compose file. You can run this docker-compose on any computer, and every computer inside your local network would have access to it (obviously, you should put the computer running the docker-compose in your local network first). Make sure the server's firewall (The computer running the docker-compose) allows traffic on the application's port.